# swift 3 global function. Can I do that way?

Tags: swift

Yes, I want easy way to call my global functions using swift 3. So I did that like below. I think is many way to do that. But I think that is most simple way. Please give some advice if you know that a lot.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

// Start observe the path value for the new one.
func SMFirdatabaseGetSingleObserveWith(path: String, theSnap: @escaping (FIRDataSnapshot) -> Void) {

    var isFirstLoad: Bool = true
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(path).queryLimited(toLast: 1).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snap) in
        if snap.exists() {

            if isFirstLoad {

               isFirstLoad = false

            }else {

                theSnap(snap)
            }

        }
    })

}
```

And when I wanna use that function . I just call it like below.

```
class Message {

    var messages: [Int] = []

    init() {
        getNewMessageIndex()
    }

    func getNewMessageIndex() {

        // Use global function here
        SMFirdatabaseGetSingleObserveWith(path: "/Message/\("uid")") { (snap) in
            messages.append(snap as! Int)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you really think this is *easy*? You will run into serious problems when the *easy* function is called from multiple threads at the same time?

Comment: Why it will called in multiple threads at the same time?

Comment: The main purpose of a global function is to be called from everywhere. A standard application runs on different concurrent threads. So you have to make sure that the function is thread-safe due to its asynchronous task to avoid unexpected behavior. A encapsulated class with instances is much easier to handle regarding thread safety.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a MessageController swift file, and then put your SMFirdatabaseGetSingleObserveWith inside that. Then create a instance of MessageController as a shared singleton which will give you access to your Message func.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class MessageController {

//MARK: - Properties 

static let shared = MessageController()

// Start observe the path value for the new one.
func SMFirdatabaseGetSingleObserveWith(path: String, theSnap: @escaping (FIRDataSnapshot) -> Void) {

var isFirstLoad: Bool = true
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(path).queryLimited(toLast: 1).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snap) in
    if snap.exists() {

        if isFirstLoad {

           isFirstLoad = false

        }else {

            theSnap(snap)
        }

    }
})
}
}
```

Then to call the function from anywhere you'd go

```
MessageController.shared.SMFirdatabaseGetSingleObserveWith(...)
```